# Label the vertical line drawn using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to label the vertical line which is drawn in gnuplot using the `set arrow` command, at the top border. How can this be done? For e.g. I have drawn a vertical line at x=-3.8, in the attached image. I want to place the label at the top border at the point where this vertical line meets the top border of the plot.[image].

Is it a best practice to label the vertical lines in this manner? I choose this way because in the plot near the point where the vertical line meets the x-axis, there is already a number. So I had no choice other than placing the label at the top border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the manual or in the gnuplot console type `help label`. You can set a label to certain coordinates with offset.

```
reset session

xPos = -3.8
set arrow 1 at xPos, graph 0 to xPos, graph 1 nohead lc "red" dt 4
set label 1 at xPos, graph 1 "myLabel" offset 0.5,-0.7

plot sin(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I found this answer useful, but occasionally the vertical line overshoots the "ceiling" of the plot. Is there a parameter controlling this? Thanks!

Comment: @DavideVenturelli the vertical line should not exceed the top border because of `graph 1` as y-coordinate. If you have a counter example, please post a new question with your script so that we can check.